# shared_from_this with derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to create shared ptr to this with shared_from_this function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class foo {
public:
    virtual void method() {
        std::cerr << "foo::method()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class foo_derived : public foo, public std::enable_shared_from_this<foo> {
public:
    void method() override {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        std::cerr << "foo_derived::method" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo_derived().method();
}
```

This code throw bad_weak_ptr from line `auto self(shared_from_this());`
I think the problem is with the fact that self is created in derived class.
I am looking for an explanation for this behaviour and would also appreciate an example of valid shared_from_this usage with derived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with inheritance. Call `method` this way instead will work: `std::make_shared<foo_derived>()->method();`

[cppreference std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)

> It is permitted to call shared_from_this **only on a previously shared
>   object**, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the
>   behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the
>   shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since
>   C++17).